# How send variables function angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How send variables **year, monthGet** function angular service from controller?

**Service**

```
myApp.factory('getJsonForCalendarService', function($resource, year, monthGet) {

        return $resource(
            '../rest/api.php',
            { method: 'getJsonForCalendar', year: year, monthGet:month},
            {'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true }}
        );

});
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.getJsonForCalendar = getJsonForCalendarService.query(function (response, year, monthGet) {
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your factory function is only ever instantiated (called/newed) once by the applications injector: You need to do this:

```
myApp.factory('getJsonForCalendarService',function($resource){
    return function(year,month){        
        return $resource(
            '../rest/api.php',
            { method: 'getJsonForCalendar', year: year, monthGet:month},
            {'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true }}
        );    
    }
}
```